# Getting Url seperated with slashes Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

How to convert below url

```
http://example.com/controller?id=value&sd=value2
```

to like below

```
http://example.com/controller/value/value1
```

Tried below

```html
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
$config['controller_trigger'] = 'c';
$config['function_trigger'] = 'm';
```

but not working

Comment: You can just use the latter url format in your pages. To handle those parameters in your controller, you can use segments - like - `$this->uri->segment(3);` - which results `value1`

Comment: You can try with CI routes. It is batter solution for your problem. ex `$route['controller/action/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'add_route_name/value/value1';`

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieve using `application/config.php` and disabling the Query Strings on the URL (this is the default option, not a clue why you've it like that unless some `.htaccess` and/or custom code is messing up with your URL). Just change the value of `enable_query_strings` to `FALSE`:

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
$config['controller_trigger'] = 'c';
$config['function_trigger'] = 'm';
```

More info:

- [CodeIgniter URLs](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html)